# Convert simple php code to python

Tags: php, python

I want to convert my php code to python code. Is it possible

```
$secret = 'segredo'; // To make the hash more difficult to reproduce.
$path   = '/p/files/top_secret.pdf'; // This is the file to send to the user.
$expire = 1096891200; // At which point in time the file should expire. time() + x; would be the usual usage.
$md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret . $path . $expire, true)); // Using binary hashing.`$md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_'); // + and / are considered special characters in URLs, see the wikipedia page linked in references.
$md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5); // When used in query parameters the base64 padding character is considered special.
```

I want to convert above php code to python. Is there exist some tool for conversion ?

This code is simple unique url generator for nginx HttpSecureLinkModule.

Comment: use http://www.php2python.com :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import hashlib
secret, path, expire = 'segredo', '/p/files/top_secret.pdf', 1096891200
md5 = hashlib.md5(secret + path + str(expire)).digest().encode('base64').strip('\n=')
```

Comment: fix: change `.hexdigest` to `.digest`